# I have a button. When I press a button, one number reduces the number in the data base. I want it to be repeated every time

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a button. When I press a button, one number reduces the number in the data base. I want when pressed each time it reduces the number by one

code html & php

```
<form method="post">
<div><?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=testt;",$username,$password);
$ser = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
$ser->execute();
foreach ($ser AS $res){
    echo '<h1>' . $res['NUMBER'];  '</h1>';
}
?></div>
<input type="submit" name="click" value="click" id="click">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['click'])){
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=testt;",$username,$password);
    $tet = 12;
    $update = $database->prepare("UPDATE test SET NUMBER=$tet-1 WHERE ID = 1");
    $update->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: Just use `test SET NUMBER=NUMBER-1` to reduce the field by one from its current value. If you use $tet you will get 11 every time obviously because you hard coded it

Comment: i am sorry i write comment mistake

Comment: Also do not use string interpolation for passing values to the database. Use [bind variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). But for the above query with decrement inside update you do not need a prepare at all, because the statement is static.

Comment: Ok so it's fixed?

Comment: yes , i have a question i echo database in div and i want to show table 1 only code echo '<h1>' . $res['NUMBER'];  '</h1>';

Comment: I didn't see a question in that comment. Its unclear what you want. Anyway don't ask new questions in the comments. If you have a new problem please ask a brand new question about it using the Ask Question feature. Make sure to actually ask something though. "I want" is not a question, and I couldn't understand what you wanted anyway. Instead, you should explain what you want, then explain the problem you're having with achieving that, and ask specifically about how to solve that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

`SET NUMBER=NUMBER-1`

to reduce the field by one from its current value. If you use `$tet` you will get 11 every time obviously because you hard coded it